# Sequelize error question

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new to node.js and sequelize, and I'm getting an error message maybe someone can help me out with. The problem seems to be with my Sequelize-defined classes: when I call their find or findAll methods, they refuse to access the database:

```
shell$ node
> var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
> var sequelize = new Sequelize("myapp", "root");
> var User = sequelize.define('User', { id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true }, email: Sequelize.STRING, password: Sequelize.STRING });
> User.find(2);
Error: deprecated: use mysql.createClient() instead
    at new Client (/Users/jay/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/mysql/lib/client.js:12:11)
    at [object Object].run (/Users/jay/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize/query.js:11:16)
    at [object Object].query (/Users/jay/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize/sequelize.js:42:52)
    at [object Object].query (/Users/jay/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize/model-definition.js:67:18)
    at [object Object].find (/Users/jay/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize/model-definition.js:136:15)
    at [object Context]:1:6
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:171:22)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:153:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:408:8)
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong and how to get this thing to work? Thanks.

Comment: Hacked a solution to this by changing line 11 in lib/sequelize/query.js to: `var client = require('mysql').createClient({` and commenting out line 24 in that same file.

Comment: Or I could have gotten a more up to date version of Sequelize. Apparently npm doesn't install the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just released v1.1.0 which supports node-mysql 0.9.4. Please give it a try and tell me if it works nicely for you.